# How do I minimize my Tkinter window whilst I run a batch file?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, onclick, minimize

I have a Tkinter window with a button. This button, on click, runs a batch file which in turn runs a test suite. This is working fine so far. But I want the Tkinter window to minimize itself when I click this button and restore itself when the batch file execution is completed. I don't know how to handle this event. Help.

Script:

```
import Tkinter
import subprocess

top=Tkinter.Tk()

def callBatchFile():
    filepath=r"C:\TestFolder\ChangeManagementBatchFile.bat"
    p=subprocess.Popen(filepath,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr=p.communicate()
    print p.returncode

button=Tkinter.Button(top,text="Execute",command=callBatchFile)

button.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
top.wm_state('iconic')
```

should minimize your win

Comment: Great! And how to restore the window again once the process is over ?

Comment: top.state('zoomed'),  nice that i could help you, if true, give Up for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. But top.state('zoomed') maximizes the window. I want it to restore itself to the same size.

Comment: top.state('normal')